# R csv to dataframe w/ strange pattern

Tags: r, dataframe, csv

How do I convert the following string to a dataframe in R?  First row is header.

```
"colA, colB, colC,<\\nValue1, Value2, Value3"
```

The `,<\\n` is screwing things up.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use `readLines`, `gsub` away the stuff, then `read.csv`.

```
x <- readLines('a.csv')
read.csv(text=gsub('<\\\\n', '', x, fixed=TRUE))
#      V1    V2    V3      V4      V5     V6
# 1 colA, colB, colC, Value1, Value2, Value3
# 2 colA, colB, colC, Value1, Value2, Value3
# 3 colA, colB, colC, Value1, Value2, Value3
```